# MVC5 Custom RequiremedAttribute based on dynamic data

Tags: custom-attributes, asp.net-mvc-5, required

I've looked all over and not found quite the answer to this question.

Is there a way to create a 'Requireable' attribute to place on a model property?

My users work for other companies.  The other companies are my clients.  My clients want the ability to specify which fields are required.

for example:

```
Model:    

[Requireable]
public string SocialSecurityNumber {get; set;}
```

When a user logs in, I'd like to get their Client and use it to set the custom requirements something like:

```
Controller:

var vm = new MyViewModel();
vm.SocialSecurityNumber.Required = Client.SSNRequired;
return View(vm);
```

I've looked at the RequiredIf concept, but that requires additional values in my view model that have to be managed through a mess of hidden fields.  But I also need to create custom fields based on clients needs and those may or may not be required as well, so a "Requireable" attribute would be super handy.

I'm sure there's got to be a clever way to do this, I'm just not finding it.

Comment: No its  not possible without using a conditional validation attribute such as `[RequiredIf]` (which only requires that your have **one** additional property and associated hidden input). Attributes are metadata and must be known at compile time

Comment: Yeah, as I've continued hunting for an answer, I'm learning more about why it's not out there.  But now my concern has to do with managing the state of the field.  If I use a requriedIf, is there a better way to carry the value of the required property through the view without putting it in a hidden field?  I'm ok with someone going in to their browsers dev tools and breaking my client side validation, but if it's just stored in a hidden field value, then they could also break my server side validation.  That'd be no bueno.

Comment: Unfortunately you need the hidden input for client side validation. You can always check that the posted value of that input matches the value it should be (and if not add a `ModelStateError`, clear `ModelState` for that property, reset its value and return the view. Or just redirect them to an error page since they are obviously a malicious user.